# Flutter call Method on onTap on a Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I´m searching for a solution for my following Problem with Flutter.
I can't call my Methods with the onTap on the Image.

I got a Page where a Bike with its Name got Displayed.
When the Image gets clicked, then the Divider should move down and three Icons should appear.

But It does not work and I don't know why.
The Icons and Divider Methods work completely fine when I call them normally and without the onTap.

This is the Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:sumo_designer/Widgets/watchyourbike.dart';
import 'package:sumo_designer/Widgets/configurator.dart';
import 'package:sumo_designer/Widgets/createnewbike.dart';

class Garage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Garage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Garage> createState() => GarageState();
}

@override
class GarageState extends State<Garage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double DividerHeightDefault = 120;
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'My Garage',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(75, 0, 75, 75),
          bottom: const PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: Divider(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 0, 255),
              thickness: 2,
              height: 0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          colors: [
                        Color.fromARGB(75, 0, 75, 75),
                        Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 100, 100),
                        Color.fromARGB(115, 0, 115, 115),
                        Color.fromARGB(130, 0, 130, 130),
                        Color.fromARGB(145, 0, 145, 145),
                      ])),
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: h * 0.8,
                          width: 160,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: w,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 140, bottom: 0, top: 0),
                          child: buildUserBikeName(context),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(children: [
                      InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 90,
                          width: 140,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/SampleBike.png'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 2,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.5),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          DividerHeightDefault + 50;
                          buildCreateViewIcon();
                          buildCreateEditIcon(context);
                          buildCreateDeleteIcon(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ]),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 0, bottom: 0, top: DividerHeightDefault),
                          child: buildDivider(context),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                          child: buildCreateDeleteIcon(context),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]))
            ]));
  }

  String UserBikeName = "SampleBikeName";

  Widget buildUserBikeName(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
        onTap: () {},
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 15,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0)),
            hintText: UserBikeName,
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 12)));
  }

  buildDivider(BuildContext context) {
    return const Divider(
      height: 15,
      thickness: 3.5,
      indent: 0,
      endIndent: 0,
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 0, 255),
    );
  }

  void buildCreateViewIcon() {
    Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return WatchYourBike();
              }),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, bottom: 0, top: 120),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded,
              size: 45.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  buildCreateEditIcon(BuildContext context) {
    Column(
      children: [
        Visibility(
            visible: false,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                    return const Configurator();
                  }),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 145, bottom: 0, top: 120),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.edit_outlined,
                  size: 45.0,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  buildCreateDeleteIcon(BuildContext context) {
    Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            buildCreateDeleteDialog(context);
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, bottom: 0, top: 120),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.delete_outlined,
              size: 45.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  buildCreateDeleteDialog(BuildContext context) {
    CupertinoAlertDialog DeleteAlert = CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: const Text("WARNING"),
        content: const Text("Are you sure you want to delete your Build?"),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: const Text("Yes"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
              child: const Text("No"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              })
        ]);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return DeleteAlert;
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put tappable widget as last child on stack. Widget tap event prioritize bottom to top as UI Also better way of using Stack with Positioned widget. Find more about [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html). Now I am just fixing tap issue here

```dart
class Garage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Garage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Garage> createState() => GarageState();
}

@override
class GarageState extends State<Garage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double DividerHeightDefault = 120;
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'My Garage',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(75, 0, 75, 75),
          bottom: const PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: Divider(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 0, 255),
              thickness: 2,
              height: 0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        colors: [
                      Color.fromARGB(75, 0, 75, 75),
                      Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 100, 100),
                      Color.fromARGB(115, 0, 115, 115),
                      Color.fromARGB(130, 0, 130, 130),
                      Color.fromARGB(145, 0, 145, 145),
                    ])),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: h * 0.8,
                          width: 160,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: w,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 140, bottom: 0, top: 0),
                          child: buildUserBikeName(context),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 0, bottom: 0, top: DividerHeightDefault),
                          child: buildDivider(context),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                          child: buildCreateDeleteIcon(context),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(children: [
                      InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 90,
                          width: 140,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            // image: const DecorationImage(
                            //   image: AssetImage('assets/SampleBike.png'),
                            //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            // ),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 2,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.5),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          print("tapped");
                          DividerHeightDefault + 50;
                          buildCreateViewIcon();
                          buildCreateEditIcon(context);
                          buildCreateDeleteIcon(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]));
  }

  String UserBikeName = "SampleBikeName";

  Widget buildUserBikeName(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
        onTap: () {},
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 15,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0)),
            hintText: UserBikeName,
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 12)));
  }

  buildDivider(BuildContext context) {
    return const Divider(
      height: 15,
      thickness: 3.5,
      indent: 0,
      endIndent: 0,
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 0, 255),
    );
  }

  void buildCreateViewIcon() {
    Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // Navigator.of(context).push(
            //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            //     return WatchYourBike();
            //   }),
            // );
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, bottom: 0, top: 120),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded,
              size: 45.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  buildCreateEditIcon(BuildContext context) {
    Column(
      children: [
        Visibility(
            visible: false,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.of(context).push(
                //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                //     return const Configurator();
                //   }),
                // );
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 145, bottom: 0, top: 120),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.edit_outlined,
                  size: 45.0,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  buildCreateDeleteIcon(BuildContext context) {
    Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            buildCreateDeleteDialog(context);
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, bottom: 0, top: 120),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.delete_outlined,
              size: 45.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  buildCreateDeleteDialog(BuildContext context) {
    CupertinoAlertDialog DeleteAlert = CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: const Text("WARNING"),
        content: const Text("Are you sure you want to delete your Build?"),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: const Text("Yes"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
              child: const Text("No"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              })
        ]);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return DeleteAlert;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you already, but did you find the Issue why the OnTap is not working?

Comment: Issue is to Stack children put an above another, And  prioritize bottom to top. Does my post working ?

Comment: In your Post you just set the Column with the Image and the onTap to the end. And that's not fixing my issue. :(

Comment: Those are inside the stack, shouldnt break the position, also your snippet seems working fine, can you simplify a widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: I just did a really simple widget and this Test Widget will be called aswell on the onTap as shown above in my complete code. `buildcreateTest(BuildContext context) {
   print("Method Start");
   Icon(
     Icons.delete_outlined,
   );
   print("Method End");
 }`

Comment: I'm testing on chrome working fine and showing print data,

Comment: The Print is working yes, but the Icon won't be displayed.

Comment: replace the widget on stack

Comment: even without the Stack it is still not working.